# Minikube deployments not working - Minikube start fails

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, minikube

Getting below error when start minikube > Exiting due to PROVIDER_DOCKER_VERSION_EXIT_1: "docker version --format -:" exit status 1: Error response from daemon: Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.
  Documentation: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/

I have tried to update the docker driver to hyperkit driver.

> Unable to update hyperkit driver: [sudo chown root:wheel /Users/SDET/.minikube/bin/docker-machine-driver-hyperkit]: exit status 1

Downloading VM boot image ...
> minikube-v1.30.1-amd64.iso....:  65 B / 65 B [---------] 100.00% ? p/s 0s
> minikube-v1.30.1-amd64.iso:  282.84 MiB / 282.84 MiB  100.00% 1.10 MiB p/
  Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
  Downloading Kubernetes v1.26.3 preload ...
> preloaded-images-k8s-v18-v1...:  31.64 MiB / 397.02 MiB  7.97% 191.66 KiB